# How to restrict Webpack `require.context` neatly?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am developing a little [static site generator](https://antwarjs.github.io/) on top of Webpack and React. Currently I'm making it more dynamic. One part of this is making it more configurable.

Given a site structure like this

```
.
├── _book
├── assets
├── build
├── drafts
├── manuscript
├── node_modules
├── pages
├── project_source
└── styles
```

I would want to require files only from certain directory or directories. In this case it would be enough to require Markdown files from `manuscript`. Naively `var req = require.context('manuscript', true, /^\.\/.*\.md$/)` would work.

The problem is that this needs to become dynamic as I pass the directory through site generator configuration. As `require.context` relies on fixed values I think I need to change context to site root using something like `var req = require.context('.', true, /^.*\.md$/)` and then check against `req.keys()` to match against my configuration.

In practice this is extremely slow as it will traverse the whole tree! Especially `node_modules` can contain a lot of files and this is something that should be avoided at all costs.

Is there a neat way to exclude `node_modules` out of `require.context`? I suppose some form of Regex might work although I am open for other ideas.

Comment: Does calling `require.context ` overwrite previous context?

Comment: @OlimSaidov The magic should happen at [paths.js](https://github.com/antwarjs/antwar/blob/f8e4061fa10494e40a7fbd12125ec8bd1fc645fd/paths.js). `config` maps to site configuration (I provide the paths there). I should be able to set up context at `allPosts` function. I hope this clarifies the situation.

Comment: Can you iterate over directories using `fs.readdirSync` and calling `require.context` ignoring `node_modules` folder?

Comment: The problem is that I'm not in Node context in that file so `fs` operations are not permitted. `paths.js` ends up in development bundle. I could trigger `fs.readdirSync` outside of this context and inject data through `config`. That wouldn't solve `require.context` issue as far as I can see.

Comment: Note that I have absolute control over Webpack configuration. Modifying that is simple. Maybe the answer is just to avoid `require.context` altogether and go through something like `resolve.alias`...

Comment: require.context should allow more fine-grained way to specify the directory and max traversal depth.

Comment: @vaughan Yeah, I agree. The API isn't ideal and regexes are a little painful. If you have time, please set up an issue and link me to it. :)

Comment: @bebraw https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the problem by pushing `require.context` outside of the static site generator and within the external configuration. I have little snippets like this there:

```
paths: {
    demo: {
        path: function() {
            return require.context('./demo', true, /^\.\/.*\.md$/);
        },
    }
}
```

Then at generator side I just consume these contexts.

It's not the solution I was hoping for but it works.

Comment: not sure this is what you are looking for https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/118

Comment: Thanks. require.context has worked just great so far. :)

Answer (score 12):

You could try:

```
var req = require.context('.', true, /^((?![\\/]node_modules|vendor[\\/]).)*\.md$/);
```

to exclude paths containing `node_modules` and `vendor` folders from the match.

Comment: Thanks! That's a cool idea. I may have to give it a go later as that would simplify my current configuration a lot and keep these things hidden from the end user.

Comment: This is still slow as the regex must be compared to every file it finds.